# Different bottom border value for footnotes

Tags: margins, footnotes, geometry

I'm using the `geometry` package to define the borders of my document:

```
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.9cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm,footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry}
```

That means the bottom of the text and the bottom of a footnote have 3cm distance to the bottom of the paper. Is is possible to define a different value for the footnote so that I can move it further down to the paper border?

Comment: I'm really not sure what is wanted here: please edit in more detail and request reopening.